# An arrow with a left inverse and a right inverse is iso.

Tags: category-theory

In the context of category theory, how can I prove that an arrow with left and right inverses is an isomosphism?

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the same as proving the same thing in a monoid.
If $g$ has a left inverse $f$, and a right inverse $h$, then on one hand $fgh = (fg)h = h$, and on the other $fgh = f(gh) = f$, so $f = h$, and $g$ has a two sided inverse.

In fact more is true: it is enough for $g$ to have a left inverse $f$ and be right-cancellable (ie. an epimorphism): since $gfg = g = \mathrm{id} ∘ g$, by cancelling $g$ on the both sides, you get $gf = \mathrm{id}$. Similarly (dually), $g$ is an isomorphism as soon as it has a right inverse and is left-cancellable (ie. a monomorphism).